# Can I use Havok Physics for free in my game?

Tags: physics, havok

I found out that Microsoft purchased the Havok physics engine. Where can I get it for Windows Visual Studio 2015 Community?

I tried to look around, but I could not find anything for the latest version. There are no download links at both the [official website](https://www.havok.com), nor on the Microsoft site.

What do I need to do to use Havok in my own game?

Comment: I couldn't find anything for a havok engine 2016 for vs2015. there's nothing on the microsoft website for a download.

Answer (score 5):

A number of years ago, when Havok was owned by Intel, they offered a binary distribution for Windows. Intel sponsored this as a marketing tool to help promote the sale of Intel processors, and to fight the idea of GPU-accelerated physics such as PhysX (which leverages NVidia's CUDA).

When Microsoft purchased Havok, they discontinued the program as they surely felt it was not in their best interest to give the product away for free.

As a result, the only way to use Havok is to purchase it. This is done by contacting Havok, and entering into negations with them.

In contrast, a product like Bullet is free for use. It might be a better option for you now that Havok is unavailable.

Comment: Very helpful and hard to find information, thanks for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Havok is a product you need to purchase. You can't just go to a website and download it until you've become a registered, licensed Havok developer.

You can contact Havok's sales team to begin this process via their [Contact Us](https://www.havok.com/contact-us/) page.